# Pass value from html to python

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, cgi

I'm using Xamp.
I have a form.

```
<form action=/cgi-bin/run.py>    
<input type="text" name="ins" id="ins">
<input type="submit" id="sub" value="submit">   
</form>
#Tag to display output from form input
</div>
<div class="output" name="output" id="output">
</div>
```

On Click of submit button. the text input is given input to my py script.
and the output is displayed in one div tag in browser.

To display output from python script back to browser. i use JS.

```
 $(sub).click(function(){ 
$.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'/cgi-bin/t1.py', 
                cache:false,                
                dataType: 'html',                                        
                success:function (z) {
                     $('#output').html(z);
                }                
        });

    });
```

My python Script:

```
#!"C:\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe"
import cgi, cgitb
print("Content-Type: text/html \n\n")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

count1=form.getvalue('ins')
print(count1)
```

If i give the form action=/cgi-bin/run.py
My js won't execute on button click.
if js won't execute, then my output won't be redirected on to same page.
It will display output of python script in seperate page.
Any approach to resolve this issue?

On button click i need to run py script ( taking input of html) and display output in div tag.

Comment: I don't quite get the question. Do you want to mimic the form submit but from Javascript instead of clicking the actual button?

Comment: Hi,
I need to execute the python script on button click, and display output of python in the div tag in html.

I used the js script to do this. But, not sure how to pass html values from js to be given as input to my python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting an answer even though I am not 100% sure of what you mean still. Try to change your Javascript to:

```
$(sub).click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from redirecting the page.
    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/cgi-bin/t1.py', // Or /cgi-bin/run.py. I'm not sure where your python script is.
            cache:false,
            dataType: 'html',
            data: $('form').serialize(), // Send the form data in the request.
            success:function (z) {
                 $('#output').html(z);
            }
    });

});
```

Comment: does     data: $('form').serialize() fetch the form contents and pass as input to my t1.py script ?

Comment: In theory, yes. Let me edit my answer for completeness, one second.